# Talend, PostgreSQL error: "Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes"

Tags: postgresql, rest, fastapi, jsonb

I am using Talend API tester to send a POST request to my FastAPI backend, and a PostgreSQL database. Please note that the table has a JSONB column. I get the error message;

"msg": "Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 10 column 3 (char 354)".

I have ensured that all property names are enclosed in double quotes but i still get the error, what am i doing wrong?

Here is the request body from Talend, with the last curly brace being on line 10 in Talend;

```
{
  "site_id": "dd63d665-1a90-41a6-baad-fa6df7ff99f3",
  "notion_link": "https://excited-fuel-931.notion.site/Q-A-by-Uwem-Uke-ef70156ea56f47408aa9f1de0a3162cc",
  "sync_data": {
    "title": "Q/A by Uwem Uke",
    "description": "Amazing website",
    "is_rtl": "true",
    "social_media_link": "https://twitter.com/uwemuke",
    "appearance": "light",
  }
}
```

Comment: Without showing the relevant code, noone will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was caused by the trailing coma in the last property:

```
 "appearance": "light",
```

That made the API client expect an additional property which apparently wasn't enclosed in double quotes. Solved it by removing the trailing coma.

```
{
  "site_id": "dd63d665-1a90-41a6-baad-fa6df7ff99f3",
  "notion_link": "https://excited-fuel-931.notion.site/Q-A-by-Uwem-Uke-ef70156ea56f47408aa9f1de0a3162cc",
  "sync_data": {
    "title": "Q/A by Uwem Uke",
    "description": "Amazing website",
    "is_rtl": "true",
    "social_media_link": "https://twitter.com/uwemuke",
    "appearance": "light"
  }
}
```